# Ember Octane upgrade: how to handle eslint error no-action

Tags: javascript, ember.js, eslint

This is related to: [Ember Octane Upgrade How to pass values from component to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60700250/ember-octane-upgrade-how-to-pass-values-from-component-to-controller)

In the ../templates/change-password.hbs file, I am receiving the following eslint error:

> Do not use `action` as {{action ...}}. Instead, use the `on` modifier
>   and `fn` helper.  no-action

Code:

```
<Clients::ChangePasswordForm @chgpwd={{this.model}} @changePassword={{action 'changePassword'}} @errors={{this.errors}} />
```

The accepted answer instructed me to use that syntax. Is there a different way I should be handling this or should I ignore the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ember Octane, linters are updated to encourage the use of `on` modifier and `fn` helper instead of `action` helper & modifier. The `action` modifier is used to bind the proper `this` context to the function. With Octane, `@action` decorators are the recommended way to bind the context to any method.

In your case, since you are passing the `changePassword` as a closure action to the component `Clients::ChangePasswordForm`, the recommended way to pass a function to a component is as follow:

```html
<Clients::ChangePasswordForm 
  @chgpwd={{this.model}}
  @changePassword={{this.changePassword}}
  @errors={{this.errors}} 
/>
```

in case, you need to pass any argument (say, `this.argument`) along with the function, use `fn` helper:

```html
<Clients::ChangePasswordForm 
  @chgpwd={{this.model}}
  @changePassword={{fn this.changePassword this.argument}}
  @errors={{this.errors}} 
/>
```

Since you've already tagged your action [with `@action` decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60700250/ember-octane-upgrade-how-to-pass-values-from-component-to-controller). You are good to go.

Here is the [official guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/upgrading/current-edition/action-on-and-fn/) on how to upgrade from classic event handlers to Octane recommended way

The lint message can be more helpful and there is already an [issue opened](https://github.com/ember-template-lint/ember-template-lint/issues/1079) on `ember-template-lint` repo to expose more useful error message while consuming classic `action` helper.