# How to get Ember Twiddle working: Route links are not displaying on the page

Tags: ember.js

This question is related to: [Ember Octane How to Clear Form Errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61005765/ember-octane-how-to-clear-form-errors)

I have been asking a lot of questions on how to upgrade my Ember Classic project to Ember Octane. Some users in the community have suggested that I post an Ember-Twiddle for them to see what is going on. I have tried doing that, but I cannot get it to work. This is another tool for me to learn and I am struggling a bit to make heads or tails of it while trying to also NOT post my entire project as that seems unnecessary.

Why do I not see the page links for `change-password` and `myroute2`?

https://ember-twiddle.com/364eaf05a2e1072994b61f255032eb62?openFiles=templates.application%5C.hbs%2C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint is the browser's console:

[image: devtools]

you first trying to extend your `change-password` from unknown mixin and after fixing that you'd see another error re unknown services in the `change-password` controllers. Comment them out and everything works.

Comment: Your answer works and I have saved the corrections - thank you. I hope you don't mind a follow-up question, but I am not getting any output on the myroute2 link? There is no error in the console. Can you please advise what is wrong?

Comment: Yep, you need to add a route template, under `/templates/clients/myroute2.hbs`