# Ember Octane: ember-g-recaptcha reCaptchaResponse comes back as undefined

Tags: ember.js, recaptcha

I am upgrading to Ember Octane and I am using ember-g-recaptcha https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-g-recaptcha. The project `README.MD` has not been updated to reflect Ember Octane. The reCaptchaResponse in the component js keeps coming back `undefined`. How do I fix this?

I have posted the Ember-Twiddle here https://ember-twiddle.com/509eb1c04c9c7d908d16ba2a2bb39ba5. Note: you will need to provide a sitekey to use it.

Thats what I do:

```
<GRecaptcha 
    @size="normal" 
    @sitekey={{this.siteKey}} 
    @onSuccess={{action "onCaptchaResolved"}} 
    @onExpired={{action "onCaptchaExpired"}} 
    @ref={{mut this.googleRecaptcha}} 
/>
```

I have posted the code in GitHub here: https://github.com/IlliterateUser/GoogleReCaptcha

Although, the page is not displaying and the console is not throwing any errors. I will need to look at this over the weekend when I have more time.

Comment: your twiddle is not really a working reproduction. :/
Maybe a git repo could work? Also sharing your site key would be OK, its also shared on your actual website.

Comment: @Lux I have posted the Git repo of a project that only intends to implement the Google reCaptcha. The form information is not displaying, so I will need to look at that this weekend when I have more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GRecaptcha addon is getting the site key from the config envirenement file, you set it as follow

```
 gReCaptcha: {
      jsUrl: 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit', // default
      siteKey: '...lQ-sUAAAA...KGVMS6zlH_xry5fon9GP1..'
    }
```

do not pass it as argument , comment the site key import

```
////import ENV from '../../config/environment';
...
//  siteKey = ENV.gRecaptcha.siteKey;
```

and call it without site key argument,

```
<GRecaptcha
          @size="normal" 
          @onSuccess={{action "onCaptchaResolved"}} 
          @onExpired={{action "onCaptchaExpired"}} 
          @ref={{mut this.googleRecaptcha}} 
 />
```

this worked for me

Comment: I think you may be missing something - I tried it and now the reCaptcha does not display on the register form. Also, in the Console, I get the following error: `Error: Missing required parameters: sitekey`

Comment: uprade the grecaptcha module to the latest version , look on the readme https://github.com/algonauti/ember-g-recaptcha#readme ,

Comment: here is my example https://github.com/amiarSlimane/ember-grecaptcha-test/blob/master/config/environment.js