# How are Ember Octane Glimmer component @actions called?

Tags: ember.js

This question is related to [Ember Octane Upgrade How to pass values from component to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60700250/ember-octane-upgrade-how-to-pass-values-from-component-to-controller)

I was struggling to receive and assign values from an HBS form into a component and then pass it to the controller. The working answer showed that I had to create an `@action` function for each form field. For example:

```
@action
changeNewPassword(ev) {
    this.newPassword = ev.target.value;
}
```

But, I do not understand where or how those functions are called and so I do not understand why they work. Does anyone know how these functions are called?

Template Component HBS

```
<div class="middle-box text-center loginscreen animated fadeInDown">
    <div>
        <h3>Change Password</h3>
        <form class="m-t" role="form" {{on "submit" this.changePassword}}>
            {{#each this.errors as |error|}}
                <div class="error-alert">{{error.detail}}</div>
            {{/each}}
            <div class="form-group">
                <Input @type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Old Password" @value={{this.oldPassword}} required="true" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <Input @type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="New Password" @value={{this.newPassword}} required="true" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <Input @type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" @value={{this.confirmPassword}} required="true" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Template HBS

```
<Clients::ChangePasswordForm @chgpwd={{this.model}} @changePassword={{action 'changePassword'}} @errors={{this.errors}} />
```

Template Component JS

```
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { tracked } from '@glimmer/tracking';
import { action } from '@ember/object';

export default class ChangePasswordForm extends Component {

    @tracked oldPassword;
    @tracked newPassword;
    @tracked confirmPassword;
    @tracked errors = [];

    @action
    changeOldPassword(ev) {
        this.oldPassword = ev.target.value;
    }
    @action
    changeNewPassword(ev) {
        this.newPassword = ev.target.value;
    }
    @action
    changeConfirmPassword(ev) {
        this.confirmPassword = ev.target.value;
    }

    @action
    changePassword(ev) {

        ev.preventDefault();

        this.args.changePassword({
            oldPassword: this.oldPassword,
            newPassword: this.newPassword,
            confirmPassword: this.confirmPassword
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you have lots of followup questions. Have you considered joining the Ember Discord?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ember Octane, you want to use the `on` modifier for setting up actions.

The line

```
<form class="m-t" role="form" {{on "submit" this.changePassword}}>
```

effectively sets up an event listener for the `submit` event of this form element which will invoke the `changePassword` function on the component's class (because the `this` in `this.changePassword` means that the function is local to the component)

That invokes this action:

```
@action
changePassword(ev) {

  ev.preventDefault();

  this.args.changePassword({
    oldPassword: this.oldPassword,
    newPassword: this.newPassword,
    confirmPassword: this.confirmPassword
  });
}
```

This `changePassword` action is in turn invoking the `changePassword` function that was passed to the component under the named argument `@changePassword`

```
<Clients::ChangePasswordForm @chgpwd={{this.model}} @changePassword={{action 'changePassword'}} @errors={{this.errors}} />
```

Now, in your `Template Component JS` you have three other actions

1. `changeOldPassword`
2. `changeNewPassword`
3. `changeConfirmPassword`

which, as far as I can tell from the code you posted, are never used. They look like code you would use to set up a 1-way bound input, but you are using the built-in `Input` which is the Ember [input built-in component](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/classes/Ember.Templates.components/methods/Input?anchor=Input) (and uses two-way binding between the input value and the `@value`). The very important distinction to note is the capital `I` on `Input`. All angle bracket components use title-casing (each separate word starts with a capital letter).

Had you instead done something like:

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="New Password" value={{this.newPassword}} {{on 'input' this.changeNewPassword}} required="true">
```

Then you would have bound the `this.changeNewPassword` function to the `input` event of the `<input>` element (which is the native html `<input>`. With the `changeNewPassword` action as you've defined:

```
@action
changeNewPassword(ev) {
  this.newPassword = ev.target.value;
}
```

You would have kept the `this.newPassword` value in sync with the input via one way binding.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways I see you are using actions in your examples.

1. Via `{{on}}`:

```
<form class="m-t" role="form" {{on "submit" this.changePassword}}>
```

This case is more straightforward. When you do `this` in a component template, you are referring to the component's class, so, `this.changePassword` is called by the template when the submit DOM event happens in the `form` element.

You can see more information in the [`{{on}}` API docs](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.17/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/on?anchor=on).

2. Via `{{action}}`

```
<Clients::ChangePasswordForm @chgpwd={{this.model}} @changePassword={{action 'changePassword'}} @errors={{this.errors}} />
```

In this case, whenever `@changePassword` is triggered inside `Clients::ChangePasswordForm`, Ember will search for a `changePassword` either in the actions hash (classic syntax) or a decorated method (`@action`) in the class of the component that is using `Clients::ChangePasswordForm`.

You can see more information in the [`{{action}}` API docs](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.17/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/on?anchor=action).

Hope this helps clarify the action mechanisms.

For extra homework, you might want to check the [upgrade guides on actions](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/upgrading/current-edition/action-on-and-fn/).